# best workaround where cant extend abstract enum java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I have a `DrivingSimulation` class that implements a `Simulation` interface.
A `Router` gets the correct route from the `Simulation` implementation.
Thus the DrivingSimulation has a `DrivingSimulationRoutes`, that is implemented with an enum `Route`. But i cant extend the abstract `Routes` or implement an `Routes` interface and return the `DrivingSimulationRoutes.Route` as a `Simulation.Route` because enum is already extended in java.

What is the best pattern to solve this problem of wanting to ensure `SimulationImplementationRoutes` has an enumerable number of routes?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific with what exactly you're trying to do. Are you attempting to have a different set of possible `Route`s for each of your simulations? What other sorts of routes might there be besides `DrivingSimulationRoute`? Why does this need to be an enum instead of just a `Collection<? extends SimulationRoute>`?

Comment: yes thats what i intend. basically, `MedicalSimulation` could have different routes for example.

Comment: So why do you need an enum instead of just a collection?

Comment: i was thinking to use a collection. i guess that is the best approach then

Comment: Can you please show some code (even if it doesn't compile) that shows you intention of how you would use it?

Comment: Try not to be more specific in what you demand than you need to be. Accepting any collection means that the enum problem goes away, and it also allows the simulation to do things like define routes dynamically. You might even just use `Iterable` if you don't need to know at the beginning how many possible routes there are.

Comment: thanks it answers my question. post as answer i guess or i can delete.